# How to compare and remove the object from array if value is same in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i am having two objects

```
let obj1 = {
  "name": "Gym",
  "createdAt": "2021/01/14 04:17:01",
  "id": "1f137fd1-0d3c-4eb0-b045-a13a77971887",
  "songs": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9"
    }
  ]
}

let obj2 = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "quidem molestiae enim", songId: "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"}
```

From the above 2 objects I need to loop the obj1 array and compare its songs.songId === obj2.songId . If value are same I need to cut that particular object from the songs array.

**Example**,

songId in `obj1.songs[0].songId === obj2.songId` . Because the value is same , have to cut the song object form the songs array. The result has to be like this.

**o/p**

```
{
  "name": "Gym",
  "createdAt": "2021/01/14 04:17:01",
  "id": "1f137fd1-0d3c-4eb0-b045-a13a77971887",
  "songs": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your suggestion or help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

> Filter method returns a new array with all array items that pass the provided function which test each item of the array.

```js
let obj1 = {
  name: 'Gym',
  createdAt: '2021/01/14 04:17:01',
  id: '1f137fd1-0d3c-4eb0-b045-a13a77971887',
  songs: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'quidem molestiae enim',
      songId: '36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9',
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'quidem molestiae enim',
      songId: 'e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9',
    },
  ],
};

const obj2 = {
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: 'quidem molestiae enim',
  songId: '36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9',
};
obj1.songs = obj1.songs.filter((x) => x.songId !== obj2.songId);
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = {
  "name": "Gym",
  "createdAt": "2021/01/14 04:17:01",
  "id": "1f137fd1-0d3c-4eb0-b045-a13a77971887",
  "songs": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9"
    }
  ]
}

var obj2 = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "quidem molestiae enim", songId: "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"}


var f2=[];
var final = obj1.songs.map(function(a){  
  if(a.songId != obj2.songId)
     f2.push(a);
});


obj1.songs = f2;
console.log(obj1);
```

Use `map` method to iterate through every information and push to another array.

Edit : I have added the `push` method whenever **a match** `push` it to another array and **then replace the main array with the created array**. I guess atleast for me it reduces a whole lot of complexity.
Other ans are also good. Things are also easy when you use `slice` or `filter` method of javascript that will also ultimately do your job. :)

Comment: You should use filter() instead. Map is for when you want to change the structure of the items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
obj1.songs = obj1.songs.filter(s => s.songId != obj2.songId)
```

```js
let obj1 = {
  "name": "Gym",
  "createdAt": "2021/01/14 04:17:01",
  "id": "1f137fd1-0d3c-4eb0-b045-a13a77971887",
  "songs": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "songId": "e0009b28-cfe4-455f-ada4-21d2b79c9ee9"
    }
  ]
}

let obj2 = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "quidem molestiae enim", songId: "36a8d4a7-eeb1-4f1a-81d4-20f3ce682da9"}

obj1.songs = obj1.songs.filter(s => s.songId != obj2.songId)

console.log('obj1', obj1)
```